# C function whose number of parameters depend on precompile switch

Tags: c

I use a code that does a bunch of different things depending on some precompiling switch. This requires changing the number of parameters of some functions. Right now, to define the functions, I do things like:

```
#define OPTION

#ifdef OPTION
function(int a){
#else
 function(int a,int b){
#endif

 int c=a+1;
#ifndef OPTION
 c += b;
#endif

 return c;
}
```

Apart from the fact that emacs indentation gets all messed up by two opened curly braces at the beginning (please help if you know how to fix that), is this the recommended way to proceed or are there simpler ways? I have looked at using unspecified number of arguments using `...`, but this makes the code messy and does not look very safy to me.

EDIT: The solution proposed by Ian Abbott below seemed appealing, but it did not work for me with gcc. Here is what I finally found, which allows not redefining several times the same function with minimal differences. (This is probably what he had in mind and the comment format did not allow to make the answer specific enough.)

```
void  function(int a
#ifdef OPTION
            , int b
#endif
){
int c=a+1;

#ifndef OPTION
 c += b;
#endif

return c;
}
```

Comment: `...` - is not an unspecified number of arguments, `func()` - is.

Comment: It's probably going to depend on the specifics of what separates the different versions of your function to figure out what the best route to take is.

Comment: How dou you deal with calls to `function` in the different versions?

Comment: You could fix emacs' messed up indentation by using a single `{` after the `#endif`. Another alternative is `int function(int a` `#ifndef OPTION` `, int b` `#endif` `) {`.

Comment: I would suggest to have separate functions for each option. It will make the code cleaner even though a bit larger (in terms of the source lines, not the binary)

Comment: For emacs I have a solution: use Vim

Comment: Ian's solution would be nice but lead to a compilation error: `stray ‘#’ in program
 int function(int a #ifndef OPTION , int b #endif ) {`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this, where you just put the entire function in the if directive.

```c
#define OPTION_A
#ifdef OPTION_A
int add(int x){
    return x+=1;
}
#else
int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
#endif
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("%d",add(10));
    return 0;
}
```